# Removable Discontinuity in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following complex function:

$$w=\frac{z-2}{z^2-4}$$

In the real plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$, we would say that there is a removable discontinuity at $z=2$, and a vertical asymptote at $z=-2$ (in the real plane we would have $x=z, y=w$).  Studying these functions in the complex plane things are a bit different.  I understand much of how different singular points are found and classified.  But in my notes from class, we did not discuss the case above.  Where the asymptote is in the real plane we would have a simple pole of order 1, but what happens with the removable discontinuity?  My assumption is that we would classify it as an isolated singularity since it is surrounded by regular points.  Is that as simple as it is?

There is also the case of when $z=\infty$, but I'm pretty clear on that i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is that $f$ has a removable singularity at $ a \in \mathbb{C}$ if $f$ is defined in a small punctured disc $ 0< \lvert z-a \rvert < \varepsilon$, (but not at $a$) and
$$\lim_{z \to a} f(z)  $$
exists.

---

The behaviour of a function as $z \to \infty $ is often more easily studied by setting $w=1/z$ and looking at $w=0$. In this case, the function becomes
$$ g(w) = f(1/w) = \frac{w^2(1/w-2)}{w^2(1/w^2-4)} = \frac{w(1-2w)}{1-4w^2}, $$
so $f$ tends to zero as $z \to \infty$. (If you want to talk about $f$ on the Riemann sphere, then $f$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z=\infty$, but we don't normally say that when working in $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: Okay, so there is such thing.  I also have the same work for the $z=\infty$.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In some text books, Ahlfors' Complex Analysis for example, removable singularities aren't really considered to be singularities. One good reason for this is that
$$\int_\gamma \frac{z-2}{z^2-4}=0$$

for any closed path $\gamma$ which has $2$ in its interior but not $-2$.

Comment: I understand that what you have yields a result, but we haven't gotten to integrals yet, so i don't really understand.

Comment: Well sufiice it to say that removable singularities aren't considered very interesting because they can be "fixed".

Comment: Okay.  Then this might be the reason my professor didn't mention them.  Thanks!

Comment: Once you get to integration, you might want to come back to this.  What you'll see is that removable singularities act the same way under integration as points where the function is analytic.